# Does differentiation change the units of measurement in mathematical equations?

Tags: derivatives

While i'm doing the math homework, I find something very strange. I am confused by a textbook's answer.

[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ22B.jpg)

[The textbook's answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Nmn.png)

So, Does differentiation change the units of measurement in mathematical equations?

Comment: It should be $cm^3s^{-1}$

Comment: The book is wrong. You and @Andrei are right. For the future: to post questions here don't use images. Write the math with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Andrei notes, the answer should be measured in $\mbox{cm}^3/\mbox{s}$. As far as the broader question is concerned, however, differentiation does indeed change the dimensions of physical quantities. Consider some function $f(x)$ depending on a physical quantity $x$. If you differentiate $f(x)$ with respect to $x$, the result will have the units of $f$, divided by the units of $x$; ie.

$$
\left[\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right]
=\frac{[f(x)]}{[x]}
$$

where $[\cdot]$ is shorthand for "the units of". If you have a time-dependent volume $V(t)$, then

$$
\left[\frac{dV(t)}{dt}\right]
=\frac{[V(t)]}{[t]}
$$

which reproduces the correct answer of $\mbox{cm}^3/\mbox{s}$, provided volume is measured in cubic centimeters and time is measured in seconds. My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750436/why-does-the-exponent-for-time-increase-when-we-integrate-acceleration-to-get-ve/4750443#4750443) may also be useful. Hope this helps!